# fargate pod idle costing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

From the aws fargate document, I understood that we get charged for the CPU and memory used.

Just to clarify, Is there any cost for idle pods also when they are not serving the traffic or out of 3 only 1 pod being used.

Answer (score 0):

Fargate charges per resources "configured" not "used". We have tried to fix the ambiguity in the docs as much as possible but if you can point to anything that is misleading please let me know because we want to make it more clear. Having that said if you want to get closer to a pay-per-use model have a look at app runner: https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/pricing/

App Runner has a concept of provisioned instances (where you pay only for memory) and active instances (where you pay for memory and CPU). TL/DR (and possibly an oversimplification): if your service is idle with App Runner you won't pay for CPU. More details in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Now, I have a much better understanding of Fargate pricing.

Comment: @mreferre I cannot find anywhere the information when App Runner decides it's idle. Is it decided regarding HTTP traffic?

Comment: We need to do a better job at explaining this. See the [Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/manage-autoscaling.html) section. TL/DR yes an instance is active when it's solicited with http traffic and idle otherwise.